# How to read performance chart?

Tags: performance-calculation

From the Flight Planning and Performance quiz for PPL, there is a question asking to calculate the distance needed for landing over 50ft barrier.

According to the example shown by the manufacturer (dashed arrows), once the wind line is intercepted, the distance needed is calculated by reading the value of the horizontal axis of the point.

According to the quiz answer (red line), the distance is calculated by following the slope of the parallel lines and reading the point intercepted on the horizontal axis.

The question is: is it correct to go straight down or to follow the shape of the parallel lines?

[image]

Comment: The example from the manufacturer's chart (black arrows) shows going straight down. Where is the quiz from?

Comment: @757toga I agree manufacturer is probably more reliable, but this question gave me doubts! The question has been extracted from PPLTutor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Someone at PPLTutor made a boo boo.  If you were supposed to follow the slope of the vertical landing distance lines the way the red vertical line does, you might as well not slope them.

It's the ***slope*** of the "*ground roll/50 ft barrier*" lines (one each for headwind, no-wind, and tailwind) that adjusts the landing distance for a given altitude and temperature, and for the slope to be meaningful, you have to be projecting straight down from the intersection point of the horizontal projection line, so that the higher and hotter you are, the landing distance increases as the slope of the line carries your vertical distance projection line to the right.